# Spring data neo4j repository is very slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, spring-data

I am using the `Neo4jRepository` to save and fetch my data. For the most part, I only use the standard methods `findById()`, `save()`, ... I noticed that some of them are very slow (up to several seconds for saving one Object).

Here is an example (I changed all the class names and took out some properties that are not important for that example):

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Node
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @Relationship(type = "ADMINISTRATES", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    @JsonProperty("administrated_gardens")
    private List<Garden> administratedGardens;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Node
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Garden {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    @JsonProperty("animals")
    private List<Animal> animals;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Node
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nickname;
    @JsonProperty("breed_id")
    private Long breedId;
    @JsonProperty("title_ids")
    private List<Long> titleIds;
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @CompositeProperty
    @JsonProperty("dynamic_properties")
    private Map<String, String> dynamicProperties;
    @Relationship(type = "IS_PROFILE_IMAGE", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private ImageData image;
}
```

Here is the logic to create an Animal for a Garden for a User:

```
@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ImageService imageService;

    @Autowired
    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GardenRepository gardenRepository;

    @Override
    public Animal createAnimal(Principal principal, Long gardenId, Animal animal) throws GardenNotFoundException {
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: START: getUser()");
        watch.start();
        User user = userService.getUser(principal);
        watch.stop();
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: getUser(): " + watch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() + "ms");
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: START: getGarden()");
        watch.start();
        Person person = userService.getGarden(user, gardenId);
        watch.stop();
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: getGarden(): " + watch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() + "ms");
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: START: animalRepository.save()");
        watch.start();
        animal = animalRepository.save(animal);
        watch.stop();
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: animalRepository.save(): " + watch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() + "ms");
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: START: gardenRepository.save()");
        watch.start();
        garden.getAnimals().add(animal);
        gardenRepository.save(garden);
        watch.stop();
        System.out.println("CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: gardenRepository.save(): " + watch.getLastTaskTimeMillis() + "ms");
        return animal;
    }
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User getUser(Principal principal) {
        MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
        return userRepository.getByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public Garden getGarden(User user, Long gardenId) throws GardenNotFoundException {
        return user.getAdministratedGardens().stream().filter(g -> g.getId().equals(gardenId)).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new GardenNotFoundException(gardenId));
    }
}
```

The repositories are all just basic `Neo4jRepository`s.
The `ImageData` just contains an Id and an URL (String). No actual image.

As you can see, in the method for saving an Animal, I measure the time of every operation. Here is an example output:

```
CREATE ANIMAL: START: getUser()
CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: getUser(): 1498ms
CREATE ANIMAL: START: getGarden()
CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: getGarden(): 0ms
CREATE ANIMAL: START: animalRepository.save()
CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: animalRepository.save(): 131ms
CREATE ANIMAL: START: gardenRepository.save()
CREATE ANIMAL: DONE: gardenRepository.save(): 4461ms
```

Fetching the User: 1,5 seconds. Saving the animal: 131 ms. Saving the garden: 4,5 seconds!!! That takes way too long.
Did I miss out on anything important for a good performance? Did I do something wrong with the modelling?
When I run queries directly against the database, it is almost instant.

Comment: I think for users it is fetching all the linked gardens, and for each garden all the linked animals, that's why it might be taking time.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Even when I fetch a user with about 3 gardens with 3 animals each, it is still very slow.